# replace data with condition in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

I have data in my sheet and want to replace but with conditions, in Column `A` I have data like this `my-photo/good-photo/rating123.jpg` want to replace these type of text with these type of text `my-photo/thisphoto/newphoto/123.jpg`.

For more in detail here is an example:

```
---------------------------------------------------
| Column A                   | Column B           |
|--------------------------------------------------
| My/photo-name/abd-120.jpg  | my/photo/120.jpg   |
| photo/you-name/sab-320.jpg | my/photo/320.jpg   |
| this/photo-my/dfg-431.jpg  | my/photo/431.jpg   |
---------------------------------------------------
```

I have values like the ones in column `A` in  my sheet and want to values like the ones in column `B` in my sheet.

I tried the find and replace tool but not got luck because every entry different.

I also tried some formulas but its not working as expected.

Comment: it's not clear what is the rule for replacing, if your filename always ends in three numbers, then just use `="my/photo/"&right(A1,7)`. If it's not always 3 digits, then are there other numbers in the original text? Is `my/photo/` independent from the input?

Comment: Is the part you want removed always between two `-`?

Comment: @MátéJuhász thanks its work just i chnage 7 to 8 and its work thanks for help ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always have the same number of digits to keep at the end of your filename, then a formula like this can solve your problem:

`="my/photo/"&right(A1,x)`

Where `x` is the number of characters you want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

If the part to remove always have the `-` denoting the split then this formula will work:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1) &"/" & MID(A1,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","}}}",2))+1,LEN(A1))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for help .. now i have two way to do this .. thanks